# Auto-Populated fields in a dynamic model not submitting

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need help on populating an object with the value of a text input field in a dynamic created form. In my controller i declared $scope.models={}. The last input field in the form below which has a default value `g.quant1` is populated by a value from the server but after submitting the form, the value is not passed. Viewing the object this way `{{models | json}}`shows empty, it only submits the last input value if the value is entered only then does models get populated with the value

```
     <div class="list" ng-repeat="g in dcs | filter:{age:'26'}">
            <div class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
             {{g.zidname}} </br>L: <input type="text" id="lll{{$index}}"  ng-model="models['l' + $index]"  name="lf{{u.gidname}}"><p>{{$index}}</p>
               </br>B: <input type="text" id="bbb{{$index}}"  ng-model="models['b' + $index]"  name="bf{{y.gidname}}">
               <!--<p>data.b{{$index}}</p>-->
               </br>D: <input type="text" id="ddd{{$index}}"  ng-model="models['d' + $index]"  name="df{{d.gidname}}">
                 <!--<p>data.d{{$index}}</p>-->
               </br>NUM: <input type="text" id="nummm{{$index}}" ng-model="models['num' + $index]"   name="numf{{y.gidname}}">

               </br>Certified Rate: <input  type="text" id="crrr{{$index}}"  ng-model="models['cr' + $index]"  name="cre{{y.gidname}}">
            <input  type="text"  ng-model="models['quan' + $index]" ng-value="g.quant1" >

             </div>
         </div>
```

my controller

```
    $scope.insert50=function(){



  var link = 'http://...';

      $http.post(link, {user: $scope.models

   }).success(function(data){

         alert(data);
      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a workaround with all your problems and created a separate [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/SRM9aUTDkRhmtlejfpGp?p=preview) for the solution. I am not sure what you are doing with `name`. For validations of each field, you need to set unique `name` for it and you need to add `required` or `ng-required` attribute based on your requirement. In plunker, I included validation for the last field which you can refer. Can you check this and let me know whether everything is working fine as you expected?

Comment: Worked perfectly well ..Thank you very much